# errors when hashing data in Python

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm hoping somebody could please assist.  When running the following code (below) in Jupyter notebook, I get an error

```
dummydata["ID_NUMBER"] = dummydata["ID_NUMBER"].to_string()
def clean_dummydata(dummydata,cols):
    for col_name in cols:
        keys = {cats: i for i,cats in str(hash(dummydata[col_name].unique()))}
        dummydata[col_name] = dummydata[col_name].apply(lambda x: keys[x])
        return dummydata
    
cols = ['ID_NUMBER'] 
dummydata = clean_dummydata(dummydata,cols)
dummydata.to_csv('anon_dummydata.csv')
```

This is the error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3140/2100616149.py in 
> 7
> 8 cols = ['ID_NUMBER']
> ----> 9 dummydata = clean_dummydata(dummydata,cols)
> 10 dummydata.to_csv('anon_dummydata.csv')
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3140/2100616149.py in
> clean_dummydata(dummydata, cols)
> 2 def clean_dummydata(dummydata,cols):
> 3     for col_name in cols:
> ----> 4         keys = {cats: i for i,cats in str(hash(dummydata[col_name].unique()))}
> 5         dummydata[col_name] = dummydata[col_name].apply(lambda x: keys[x])
> 6         return dummydata
>
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Answer (score 0):

Mutable types like NumPy arrays and lists are not hashable because they could change and break the lookup based on the hashing algorithm.

So, you can use hash only with immutable datatypes like a tuple. So, you can convert your numpy array into a tuple and then hash it, for eg:

```
import numpy as np
z = np.array(['one', 'two', 'three'])
tuple_z = tuple(z)
hash_z = hash(z)
```

and it should run perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately that is still giving me the same error.  I am also specifically trying to hash a unique identifier in a dataset (imported from excel/csv), so if you have any suggestions around that, it would be much appreciated